# HTML5 Canvas Animated Images Don't Load in Mobile Device Browsers

Tags: android, html, image, canvas, load

```
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

/*$("canvas").mousemove(function (event) {
    imj.x = event.pageX - 80;
    imj.y = event.pageY - 80;
});*/

function img(image, x, y, sorc) {
    image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
    }
    image.src = sorc;
}

var imj = {
    img: new Image(),
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    img(imj.img, imj.x, imj.y, "http://sr.photos3.fotosearch.com/bthumb/CSP/CSP823/k8237713.jpg");
    imj.x += 1;
    imj.y += 1;
}

setInterval(function () { render(); }, 40);
```

When I load this code (along with the HTML), it works fine on my laptop, but on my Nexus 7, the image shows up once and then disappears. And if I make the image stay in place, it does show up on my tablet. Why? (you can try it yourself or see all the code here http://pixelempire.t15.org/mobile.html)

Comment: What browser your using on laptop ? on tablet?

Comment: @JonasCz I'm using IE on my laptop but Chrome on tablet, though my friend has tried it on his laptop with Chrome and it worked the same as IE on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the issue you are having but i'm gonna try and help.  I doubt it has anything to do with your browser.  Something similar happend to me and basically it was the images not loading, try and preload the images on a different screen or load them on what ever screen you are trying to show them on and then draw them to your canvas.

Here is a link with some examples of preloading images

http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/